# Sequelize eager loading association with through table

Tags: node.js, associations, sequelize.js

I've been through several questions on the site but I still can't see what I'm doing wrong here, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm getting the error:

```
Organization (organizations) is not associated to User!
```

Org Model:

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('Organization', {

        organizationID: {
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false,
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        description: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true,
        }
    },
    {
        tableName: "spa_vOrganization",
        freezeTableName: true,
        classMethods: {
            associate: function (models) {
                Organization.hasMany(models.User, {
                    as: 'users',
                    through: models.User_Tenant_Organization,
                    foreignKey: 'organizationID'
                });
            }
        },
    });
};
```

User Model:

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('User', {
            userID: {
                primaryKey: true,
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
                allowNull: false,
            },
            password: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull: false,
            },
            email: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull: false,
            }
        },
        {
            tableName: "spa_User",
            freezeTableName: true,
            classMethods: {
                associate: function(models) {
                    User.hasMany(models.Organization, { as: "organizations", through: models.User_Tenant_Organization, foreignKey: 'userID'});
                }
            }
        }
    );
};
```

Matrix table model:

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('User_Tenant_Organization', {

        userTenantOrganizationID: {
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false,
        },
        userID: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false,
        },
        organizationID: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false,
        },
        tenantID: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false,
        },
    },
    {
        tableName: "spa_User_Tenant_Organization",
        freezeTableName: true,
    });
};
```

What I'm trying to do is just pull back a user with their organizations eagerly loaded. Here's what I'm using:

```
models.User.findOne({where: {
        email: body.email
    }, include: [ {model:models.Organization, as: 'organizations'}]}).complete( function (err, user)     {
// do something with the user
}
```

I've tried with and without `foreignKey` definitions on both `User` and `Organization`, nothing makes any difference. I'm obviously misunderstanding something about the associations.  Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. The associations in the above code are actually correct - what was failing was my models/index.js, which had been automatically generated by the yeoman generator-angular-express-sequelize

index.js was looping through the model files, importing them into the sequelize object and storing a copy in an array db[], then trying to run the classMethod associate(), but it was calling models.options.associate() instead of models.associate():

```
Object.keys(db).forEach(function (modelName) {
    if (db[modelName].options.hasOwnProperty('associate')) {
        db[modelName].options.associate(db);
    }
});
```

I've fixed that by removing the ".options" and everything works fine.

Pull request to fix the problem is here for reference: https://github.com/rayokota/generator-angular-express-sequelize/pull/7